# Embedded expression for non-string values shows error in Karate framework

Tags: karate

I want to use embedded expressions in JSON for keys containing non-string values like Integer and Boolean.

```
* def employee1 = { fName: '#(fnameVal)', lName: '#(lnameVal)', id: #(idVal), isManger: #(isManager)}
```

I used the same pattern explained for the String value in [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#embedded-expressions) but it was feeding values as String. So I just removed single quotes and it worked fine. But IntelliJ shows an error as " expected".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes, it is the right thing to do. When Karate substitutes a number or boolean, it will remove the quotes.

This is the advantage of embedded expressions, you can put them in a `*.json` file and it will be valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Somehow it did not work earlier for me but when I retried it worked. I must have missed something.